# Adding a JAR file to an Android application

Tags: android, twitter, jar

I want to add the jTwitter library to my application.

How can I add and build the path for it?

Comment: @Nikki: Are using Eclipise IDE?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572930/android-adding-external-libraries-to-project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hai Nikki,

If you are using Eclipise IDE, then follow these steps shown below.
step1:
Right click the project Name, there yiu find a option Build path(Refer Figure1)

step2: click Build path then configure Build path(Refer figure2), a dialog box will appear, in that click Add External Jars , select and add it(refer figure3).

figure 1:

[image]

figure2:

[image]

figure 3:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using Eclipse go to *Project* → *Properties* there navigate to *Java Build Path* on the tab *Libraries* hit the *Add External JARs* button and select your JAR file.