# Adding jar library to android project

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add jar file to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203447/how-to-add-jar-file-to-android-application)

I am new to Android development. I have ksoap2.jar file. I want to add it to my existing android project. I using command line android to create the project and ant to build it.

In which folder I should put this jar file and how to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In which folder I should put this jar file

Put it in `libs/`.

> and how to use it?

According to [the kSOAP2 site](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/):

> The kSOAP JavaDoc and some examples are contained in the source distribution.

Comment: I had kept the jar file in libs folder and when I am importing it like `import org.ksoap2` then it is giving an error while building... `package org does not exist`