# android rest client , SDK problem

Tags: android

i am using this [tutorial](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet/version/25) to make android as a Rest client . The problem which i am facing is "The API level for the selected SDK target does not match the Min SDK Version." while calling the source code which is provided over there .For the other project its working well can support upto SDK 10 . The other query i want to ask is that for org.restlet.jar i have to download it and set a path for it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, [Adding a JAR file to an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203447/how-to-add-jar-file-to-android-application/4203489#4203489) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set min-sdk-level higher than target-sdk-level?

Comment: thnaks for your concern . yeah i have tried but doesn't worked then wht i have done is that i have open the android manifest file and changed the version from 5 to other other version . the problem disappeared and its comes in the workspace but still i have a cross on my application ...